# Select e.g AS01 and getting the Database entry A* as a result without using the ">=" operator

Tags: database, t-sql, select, wildcard

Hello beloving community,

thanks in advance for your time and engagement.
I stumbled across a major issue:

Simplified the table i run queries on looks like:

**T1**
**ID   -   KEY   -   VALUE**
1    -   K1    -  A*
2    -   K2    -  Q*
3    -   K3    -  AS*
4    -   K4    -  Z1*

The "*" in this database serves as a wildcard, meaning any VALUE starting with **A** would be covered by **K1**, and any VALUE startng with **Z1** would be covered by **K4**.
The query would look like:

SELECT KEY
FROM T1
WHERE VALUE='AS01'

Now the problem is getting the keys **K1** and **K3** as a result, without using the "Between" function since i only got one column.
Neither i can't use the ">=" operator, since the table has over 500k entries.
Furthermore the ">=" operator would deliver me **K2 and K4** as result...

I tried using wildcards and the LIKE function, but i can't seem to get the right results.

I would be grateful if anyone of you could help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance

Yours,
Jenny

Comment: Wildcards and `LIKE` should do the trick; so can you show us some sample data and the results you are getting with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT KEY
FROM T1
WHERE VALUE='A*'
   OR VALUE='AS*'
   OR VALUE='AS0*'
   OR VALUE='AS01*'

SELECT KEY
FROM T1
WHERE VALUE in ('A*','AS*','AS0*','AS01*')
```

The problem with below is would find AB*
I don't see any way to get there without listing em out.

```
SELECT KEY
FROM T1
WHERE VALUE >='A*'
  AND VALUE <='AS01*'
```

Comment: Hey Blam thank you very much for your reply.
That would be a manual way to do it. I have thought about it too. The problem with this is, that it would mean a huge effort to put them all in the code, since the keys can go to n-letters and i'm not only querying one Value, usually the query contains 20+ values :(
Is there anyway to manage this automatically, with a function?

Comment: At a TSQL level it is efficient.  If you are going to automate it then go with in ('A*', 'AS*' ).  I don't know functions that well but that is what I would try.